# GAE Python Microservice is not working

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I have the default GAE service working, although I want to implement a microservice. The default version has two versions, and I'm implementing the microservice in just one of them, because I need to test it before to put it in the main version. For this new microservice I've created the files my_module.py and my_module.yaml. When I run the code "*appcfg.py update my_module.py*" the upload/update works perfectly as the log bellow shows:

```
10:28 AM Host: appengine.google.com
10:28 AM Application: application_name; module: my_module; version: one
10:28 AM Starting update of app: application_name, module: my_module, version: one
10:28 AM Getting current resource limits.
10:28 AM Scanning files on local disk.
10:28 AM Cloning 2 application files.
10:28 AM Compilation starting.
10:28 AM Compilation completed.
10:28 AM Starting deployment.
10:28 AM Checking if deployment succeeded.
10:28 AM Deployment successful.
10:28 AM Checking if updated app version is serving.
10:28 AM Completed update of app: application_name, module: my_module, version: one
```

However, when I go to console.cloud.google.com to check the log I constantly see an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
ImportError: No module named my_module
```

Please, does someone know why it is happening?

---

**UPDATE**: I'm putting my code of the new microservice.

my_module.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RedirectHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write('Hello!')
        return

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

my_module.yaml

```
application: application_name
module: my_module
version: one
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

instance_class: B1
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
  idle_timeout: 13s

skip_files:
- ^(./)?app.yaml
- ^(./)?app.yml
- ^(./)?index.yaml
- ^(./)?index.yml
- ^(./)?#.#
- ^(./)?.~
- ^(./)?..py[co]
- ^(./)?./RCS/.*
- ^(./)?..
- ^(./)?tests$
- ^(./)?node_modules/.*
- ^(./)?Gruntfile.js
- ^(./)?package.json

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: my_module.app
```

**UPDATE**: **The solution**

As Avinash Raj suggest in the comments, I just removed the *- ^(./)?..* from my_module.yaml and it started to work.

Comment: remove `^(./)?..` regex stmt.. unescaped dot in a regex not only matches a dot but also matches any single character. If you really mean a dot then escape it, `\.\.`

Comment: I donno why you add many regexes on skip_files section.

Comment: Hi AvinashRaj, actually what you suggested to me to do worked. Thank you very much.
I added so much because it's part of another big project and I just keep the regexes from it.

Comment: added my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to remove  `^(./)?..` regex stmt from the `skip_files` section because unescaped dot in a regex not only matches a dot but also it matches any single character which results in skipping of any file having atleast two letters in their names. If you really mean a dot then escape it like `^(./)?\.\.`

Comment: It worked for me, I ended up removing it and appengine started to work